# Play chess, login on a FICS server

Tags: defun, games

I wish to play chess with `chess.el` on a FICS server using M-x chess-ics but using that logs me as a guest player. How can I login with my registered user/password?

EDIT

I've come with a way to login. At the beginning of `chess-ics.el` comes a list of servers, I can edit it and add my username (or handle) in front of `"freechess.org"` `5000` as a new arg for connection. Then `M-x chess-isc` will ask me my password and that's it. (I have to use set seek 1 when already logged in to get the extra seek buffer, and set availinfo 0 to stop  the annoying noise on  the `freechess` buffer).

Anyway, now my issue is this, I don't like editing the `chess-ics.el` file to tell that I want to log in as my username. How can I tell `M-x chess-ics` that I want to use my username for connection? I've tried `C-u M-x chess-ics` but it seems the `chess-ics.el` script doesn't support that.

I am guessing I need to make some custom command or something (sorry for the newbie language here) so that I can call not  the default (`chess-ics`) but the `(chess-ics my-username)` which in turns calls what I want. Am I right? So I need to defun something and overwrite the default `M-x chess-ics` to call my new function. Is  that it? What would be the correct syntax  to do this. I'm really pretty new on hacking emacs lisp :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, got it, I made this and setted it up on my init scripts:

```
;; Chess ICS
(defun playchess ()
  (interactive)
  (setq username (read-string "Username: "))
  (if (string= username "guest")
      (chess-ics "freechess.org" 5000 username)
    (setq pass (read-passwd "Password: "))
    (chess-ics "freechess.org" 5000 username pass)
    )
  )
(provide 'playchess)
```

Answer (score 2):

From a quick scan of chess-ics.el (I've not used it myself so haven't verified this) it looks as though you ought to be able to configure `chess-ics-server-list` to include a handle and password on a per server basis, or you should be able to set `chess-ics-handle` and `chess-ics-password` from your init file.

Comment: thanks a lot, I've been playing around with this and now found a certain way  to do  this. Editing the question to reflect my current issue

Comment: You shouldn't need to edit chess-ics.el at all.  `chess-ics-server-list` just needs to be updated to include handle and if necessary password.  You should be able to do this either through the customize interface or by modifying your Emacs init file.  I looked at Customize -> Applications -> Games -> Chess but couldn't see how to configure it there (you might be more lucky though).  If you want to set it in your init file then you should just need to add something like `(setq chess-ics-server-list '(("freechess.org" 5000 "myhandle" "mypassword) ("chess.unix-ag.uni-kl.de" 5000) etc.))`.